# Is there a way in dart to assign a value dynamically as int and as String

Tags: typescript, flutter, variables, dart, types

I work on a flutter project, and i wonder if there is a way to do as following in typescript but in dart:

```
class Foo {myVar: string | number} //in typescript
```

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1222 Discussion around this here. Natively, no, not currently possible. But alternatives exist.

Comment: Unions can be used. Freezed package allow that.

Comment: If you just want to assign a value that could be int or string you can use dynamic.